# Gravity Keep Ball In Screen

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit

I have a problem where I am spawning balls at the the of the screen and they fall at the standard speed. However, once they reach the bottom, they just fall right through and are removed. How do I make it so that they are kept in the screen?

If it helps, I have a function where I make the ball and set its properties. (similar to a class). Another function where I add the ball to the screen (add child) and make random coords. And a final function where I have the ball endlessly spawn at the top of the screen.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ChristianWoerz Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D This is quite simple, therefore this would be easy for you as well!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define an `physics body edge` and set it to the `physicsBody` of the scene.

```
let edgeFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: edgeFrame)
```